# How to make a score be recorded as team?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to make a Lives counter for two separate teams. My original idea was to set up a dummy score titled Team Lives:

```
/scoreboard objectives add lives dummy Team Lives
```

The display is perfect except the dummy names `TeamBlue` and `TeamRed` don't show the color of the team they are added to even when I added the color option to team red and blue to red and blue respectively.
My main problem is that I do not know how to make the Lives counter decrease upon a single teammates death. I tried setting up a death counter and adding a repeating command block with the command

```
scoreboard players operation @a[team=blue] deaths > @a[team=blue] deaths
```

but that gives an Invalid Argument deaths <- [HERE] which doesn't make sense since that command works in the chat bar. Then I needed a command which will remove a point when someone on one team has a score of one to remove one life. I was thinking of setting up a repeating command block with the command

```
execute if score deaths @[team=TeamBlue] = (some entity with one death) deaths run scoreboard players TeamBlue remove Lives 1
```

but that requires 20 command blocks, so if anyone knows how to compress it, I will gladly accept it. My main issue is the fact that the scoreboard operation command is not working in the command block

Comment: Can't you use a regular "detect death" thing and then reduce the "lives" scoreboard based on that? Something like `execute as @a[team=TeamBlue,scores={deaths=1}] run scoreboard players remove dummyEntity Lives 1` and then `scoreboard players reset @a[team=TeamBlue] deaths`? That's the standard way to detect deaths.

Comment: That seems to work. Thank you for all your help. Also the color is working now. I think the game just needed to be relogged.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment:
You need a regular "detect player death" system and the thing you run from it is the decrease of the "Lives" score. You don't even need to sum up all player deaths in a central score.

```
execute as @a[team=TeamBlue,scores={deaths=1}] run scoreboard players remove dummyEntity Lives 1
scoreboard players reset @a[team=TeamBlue] deaths
```