# Command blocks: checking team, and score of players, and summing up values

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to use command blocks to set up a team death counter for my friends server. We wanted to have a scoreboard that just displays how many deaths a single team has.

I currently have the scoreboards set up with a death objective which counts how many deathcount of each individual person and displays it under their name. I wanted to try using command blocks to set dummy scores on dummy players to be the sum of the deaths each member on the team has.

This is my first time doing command blocks, so if there is a better way to achieve what we want, then it is more than welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a score be recorded as team?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330080/how-to-make-a-score-be-recorded-as-team)

Comment: I wanted to say something like "I like pointing more people to my answers, but this time I disagree with the duplicate parent", but it turns out that the better duplicate parent I found is **also** answered by me! It's getting hard to find questions that I have not yet answered. :D Since both answers can be helpful in different cases, I'll try out this fancy double-duplicate thing. Edit: Actually, the system already does that automatically.